# if text box array how to add to listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a slight issue with my program. I'm a first year student and am trying to make a program on flight reservation.

```
if (txtSeat.Text == "1")
{
   btnRowOneSeatOne.BackColor = Color.Red;
   goodMessage += "You Selected Row One and Seat One";
}
```

So, this basically goes down for all 15 seats in the same manner. I have a textbox and if you type numbers from 1-15 the seat will button turn red.

I also did pretty much the same thing in removing the customer. As followed

This was in the remove button handle

```
if (txtRemove.Text == "1")
{
       btnRowOneSeatOne.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
```

I haven't started on an array yet. Basically for that I have a text box once the number is enter it should store it in the array.

I believe this should be the coding

```
seatNum = int.Parse(txtSeat.Text);
bool availability = false;

for (int s = 0; s < seats.Length; s++)
{
    seats[s] = seatNum
    availability = true;
    break;
}
if (availability == true)
{
}
```

I believe this should store the seat in array. I've tried many different ways, but couldn't seem to find away. This is an assignment for a class FYI.

Comment: not sure what you want.

Comment: I apologize for not explaining this well. What I need is two things. I'm trying to store number data from a textbook into the array, which is the last coding I have in my main post, but I'm getting a problems with that code. The other thing was that once the array is full I would like to add it to a listbox, which I'm not sure on how to do.

Comment: How does the input data look like in your textbox? a comma-separated string? or any other pattern? You should make it clear on that.

Comment: Thank you four response again. I'll try being as clear as possible. I have 15 buttons and each button has a number assigned to it from 1-15. When you enter one of the numbers into the text box and hit add to flight button the button backcolor changes to red and with a message box popping up informing passenger has been added. I basically want that text box in which I enter the number in to store all that data into the array and if you try selecting the number again I want to add the passenger into the a listbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
          int seatnum = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
         Seat = new int[15];
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            Seat[seatnum - 1] = seatnum;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            if (Seat[i] != 0)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried this code and it works, but it isn't what I'm actually looking for. When I put this code in right when I hit my button to add it puts the number in the list. What I'm looking for is first I need to make sure that whatever i type in the text box (numbers) it adds to my array and once I get that I'd like to add people to the list once the array is full.